# Unit Testing Order of Enum

Tags: c#, unit-testing, enums, tdd

I have an enum that is ordered, representing sections of a grocery store in the order I traverse them.

```
enum Departments { Produce=0, Bulk=1, Deli=2, Frozen=3, NonFood=4, Bakery=5, DryGoods=6 }
```

Now I have some class representing items to get that have a name and a department:

```
class GroceryItem : IComparable<GroceryItem>
{
    string Name;
    Departments Department;
}
```

the proper sorting function sorts the grocery list alphabetically by Department, so I can minimize my traversal of the store.

Would it be valuable to unit test this enum for order, or should I be using some other data structure to hold department?

Comment: Is the order of the enum significant? It doesn't seem to be related to the alphabetic sort you're doing later.

Comment: Yes, maybe I misworded the sort order, I want to sort items by their department then alphabetically, so [Bread (Bakery), Dog Food (Bulk), Carrots (Produce), Oranges (Produce)] gets sorted to [Carrots, Oranges, Dog Food, Bread]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the sorting is a business requirement, I'd write a test for the method producing (and possibly displaying) the sorted results. Pass it an unordered collection of `GroceryItem`s and verify the order is correct.

Putting a test *only* on the enum is probably the wrong way to go (though you can do both tests). The reason I say that, is that you're not guaranteeing your code *actually* sorts by department.

These would all go undetected:

```
groceryItems.OrderBy(g => g.Name).ThenBy(g => g.Department);

groceryItems.OrderByDescending(g => g.Department).ThenBy(g => g.Department);

groceryItems.OrderBy(g => g.Name);

groceryItems.OrderBy(g => g.Department);
```

Even though the enum is correctly sorted.

Comment: Since I'm using IComparable, then I need to test a collection containing 1 object for each department, sort it, then ensure that they are in the right order afterwords?

Comment: Pretty much - yes. Though I'd have two/three items for each department, to check that the `ThenBy` sort also works